# Javascript bitwise to c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have some issue to convert a javascript code into c# the issue is with bitwise operator:

Javascript function:
return (s - (s | 0x0)) * 0x100000000 | 0x0;

C# function;
return (long)((s - ((long)s)) * 0x100000000);

If s = 1.7320508075688772
on Javascript report -1150833019
on c# report 3144134277

other example can be Javascript: (1779033703 << 0x1e) = -1073741824
c# (1779033703 << 0x1e) = 1910222893216694272

What i need is translate Javascript function into c# with same number result.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don’t know C# syntax that well, but `(int)3144134277U` or `(int)3144134277UL`, maybe? `>>` produces a signed 32-bit integer in JavaScript when used on a `number`.

Comment: you cant use int cause is over range (32-bit signed integer type -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)

Comment: Do you know what the *purpose* of this operation is? It looks like you're trying to reinterpret an `int` as a `uint` and sign-extend it to a `long`. Whatever it is, though, there's probably a more natural, idiomatic way of doing in C# whatever it's intended to accomplish but we need to examine its purpose first.

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited description

Answer (score 3):

So, there are a few things going on here.

1. You have a type mismatch in your JavaScript.  In Hex, `3144134277` is `BB67AE85`, and `-1150833019` is `FFFFFFFFBB67AE85`.  So, we can see that the JavaScript int32 is being implicitly converted to an unsigned int64.
2. You can't bitshift by 0.  Bitshifting is dividing by `2^n`, where n is, in this case, 0.  That returns the same number, as `2^0 = 1`.
3. (long)((ulong)(…) That's a double cast, and is considered bad form.  Your number literal will be cast to an unsigned long, then cast again to a long.  This just wastes cycles.
4. Your cast is a C style cast, in C# casting is more often done as object.ToInt()

So, in review, you have a bug in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the same behavior on C# by default. Because:

- In JavaScript, a number is stored as a 64-bit floating point number
     but the bit-wise operation is performed on a 32-bit binary number
- So to perform a bit-operation JavaScript converts the number into a
  32-bit binary number, perform the operation and convert back the
  result to a 64-bit number.

So in your case you might be trying to cast a 64-bit number to 32-bit one and get a faulty result from there. Which in C# it wouldn't be a good thing to have in my opinion.

Comment: This underscores the need to understand the function's purpose and try to match that instead of doing a direct translation.